# How to do a netstat to see if a port is in use in C++?

Tags: c++, port, netstat

From the command prompt, I can run netstat to see if a single port is already in use on a machine something like this:

```
netstat -nap | grep <port-num>
```

What functions could I call in C++ on Linux to just see whether a particular port is presently in use or not?  I'd rather not do a system call to netstat itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756107/how-to-check-if-port-is-available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do:

```
strace netstat -nap
```

You can deduce what netstat is doing to get that information.

For example:

```
open directory: openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/2073/fd", ...) = 4)
get entries: getdents(4, /* 15 entries */, 32768)    = 360
read symbolic links: readlink("/proc/2073/fd/4", "socket:[48395]", 29) = 14 
that one was a socket connected on port 48395
```

Comment: I don't see how strace is a C++ function to call?

Comment: This is something OS-specific and you will not have a C++ function to call. You will need to basically use an OS-specific set of libraries. The strace command gives you system calls on Linux. The same will not work on Windows and you'll need to use another profiler if you want the result (truss on Solaris for example). However the above is the best way to explore on Linux.

BTW what perreal says is that you need to use the system calls 'openat', 'getdents' and 'readlink' if you want to replicate the behavior of 'netstat -nap'.